# How can I send photo to telegram user with telethon

Tags: python, telegram, sendmessage, telethon

Currently I'm using this method that sends text to user but how can I send photo to user with module Telethon

```
client.send_message(receiver, message.format(user['name'])
```

Comment: Did you look at Telethons [Documentaton for the Client](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#client-ref)? It has methods named "send_file" and "upload_file" which might help you.

Answer (score 3):

As @vlz said in the comment, [`client.send_file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file) [listed in the documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#uploads) is the right method to use:

```py
# note: local paths work just as well
# note: await is needed if used inside async def
await client.send_file(receiver, '/path/to/photo.jpg')
```